# Non FK models tied together by ID (unmanaged model) - how to filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models that are related - but they are not a FK relationship in Django because one is a non-managed model with the data coming from a pre-populated DB table.

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    # This comes from a 'shared app' that is used in other projects 
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="ID", primary_key=True)
    location_id = models.IntegerField(db_column="locationID")
    grade = models.CharField(db_column="grade", max_length=10)

    class Meta(object):
        managed = False
        db_table = "mytable_Enrollments"

class Location(models.Model):
    # This model exists in an app in the specific project I am working on
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    alternate_name = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm trying to filter `Enrollment` models using a list of `Location` models - but they are not tied together in a FK relationship.

I am trying to get enrollments for a particular location like this:

```
# This does not work properly because it is returning an empty Queryset when it should have results - but does not hit the db which is what I want
location_ids = Location.objects.filter(id=1).values_list("id", flat=True)
enrollments = Enrollment.objects.filter(location_id__in=location_ids)
```

The above code returns an empty queryset.

If I cast `location_ids` to a list (like this: `list(location_ids)`) and then filter on that, it works.

```
# This works properly - but hits the db which is NOT what I want
location_ids = Location.objects.filter(id=1).values_list("id", flat=True)
enrollments = Enrollment.objects.filter(location_id__in=list(location_ids))
```

Is there a way to use the Django ORM to get what I want in this case without causing it to evaluate the queryset?

Additionally, I have tried just returning `values` instead of `values_list` but it also returns an empty Queryset when it should not.

```
# This returns empty queryset
location_ids = Location.objects.filter(id=1).values("id")
enrollments = Enrollment.objects.filter(location_id__in=location_ids)
```

Comment: That model comes from a 'shared app', that if I used a FK would break in other apps where it gets used I believe. `Enrollments` and `Location` are in 2 different apps. 

When I say "does not work properly" I mean that it returns an empty Queryset when it should have results. I will update the question.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Are they on the same database?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the database for a QuerySet at any point in the QuerySet “chain.” Call using() on the QuerySet to get another QuerySet that uses the specified database.

`using()` takes a single argument: the alias of the database on which you want to run the query. in your example, edit it like this:

```
location_ids = Location.objects.using("currentdb").filter(id=1).values("id")
enrollments = Enrollment.objects.using("currentdb").filter(location_id__in=location_ids)
```

source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database